# Inserting table in landscape mode using IEEE template

Tags: tables, landscape

I am writing a paper for IEEE transaction in which I have to insert a table in landscape mode which will fill the whole page. But, apparently, the table is using the whole space of the page. I have utilized the showframe package and it appears that by-default template margins do not allow to fit the table in the page. Is there any work around? or can someone suggest me what is the best way to insert a table in landscape mode for IEEE papers?

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{color,colortbl}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{lscape}
\begin{document}
\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{landscape}
    \begin{table*}[h!]
        \centering
        \caption{Quality and Computational Time of Proposed CCI-based SDP Relaxation for Multi-Phase Networks for $R_{gnd}=1\Omega$}
        \scriptsize
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            \multicolumn{26}{|c|}{\cellcolor{gray!50}\textbf{OF:1}}\\ \hline
            \textbf{LMs}&\multicolumn{5}{c|}{{\thead{\textbf{MG}\\\textit{(LuB)}}}}&\multicolumn{5}{c|}{{\thead{\textbf{IT-37}\\\textit{(MuB)}}}}&\multicolumn{5}{c|}{{\thead{\textbf{IT-111}$^\dagger$\\\textit{(MuB)}}}}&\multicolumn{5}{c|}{{\thead{\textbf{Cigre}\\\textit{(HuB)}}}}&\multicolumn{5}{c|}{{\thead{\textbf{IEEE}\\\textit{(HuB)}}}}\\ \hline
            &{\thead{EVR \\$|\lambda_2|/|\lambda_1| \times 10^{-5}$}}&OV&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{\% Optimality Gap}&{\thead{EVR \\$|\lambda_2|/|\lambda_1| \times 10^{-5}$}}&OV&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{\% Optimality Gap}&{\thead{EVR \\$|\lambda_2|/|\lambda_1| \times 10^{-5}$}}&OV&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{\% Optimality Gap}&{\thead{EVR \\$|\lambda_2|/|\lambda_1| \times 10^{-5}$}}&OV&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{\% Optimality Gap}&{\thead{EVR \\$|\lambda_2|/|\lambda_1| \times 10^{-5}$}}&OV&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{\% Optimality Gap}\\ \hline 
        \end{tabular}
%       \begin{tablenotes}\scriptsize
%           \centering 
%           \item LM: Load Model \hspace{1em} MG: Micro Grid \hspace{1em} \hspace{1em} IT: Italian \hspace{1em} $\dagger$: Memory Limit \hspace{1em} \\ \textit{LuB}: Lightly Unbalanced \hspace{1em} \textit{MuB}: Moderately Unbalanced \hspace{1em} \textit{HuB}: Highly Unbalanced
%       \end{tablenotes}
        \label{Table_3}
    \end{table*}
\clearpage
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Comment: BTW, table* does not support [h].  In any case you should probably be using [p] and \rotatebox (graphicx package} instead of landscape.  Not that that make your table any smaller.

Answer (score 2):

Some suggestions:

- Load a font package that provides a Times Roman-type math font. (The text font is a Times Roman clone.)
- Allow line breaks in the `\% Optimality Gap` headers
- To save still more space, replace all instances of `|\lambda_2|/|\lambda_1| \times` with `|\lambda_2/\lambda_1| \cdot`.
- Use the `\SI` macro of the `siunitx` package to typeset scientific units (such as `\ohm`).

[image]

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tabularx}
%%\usepackage{color,colortbl}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{showframe}
%\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{rotating,siunitx} % <-- new
\sisetup{detect-all}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\scriptsize
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\centering

\caption{Quality and Computational Time of Proposed CCI-based SDP Relaxation for Multi-Phase Networks for $R_{\mathrm{gnd}}=\SI{1}{\ohm}$}
\label{Table_3}

\begin{tabular}{|*{16}{c|}}
     \hline
     \multicolumn{16}{|c|}{\cellcolor{gray!50}\textbf{OF:1}}\\
     \hline
     \textbf{LMs}
     &\multicolumn{3}{c|}{{\thead{\textbf{MG}\\\textit{(LuB)}}}}
     &\multicolumn{3}{c|}{{\thead{\textbf{IT-37}\\\textit{(MuB)}}}}
     &\multicolumn{3}{c|}{{\thead{\textbf{IT-111}$^\dagger$\\\textit{(MuB)}}}}
     &\multicolumn{3}{c|}{{\thead{\textbf{Cigre}\\\textit{(HuB)}}}}
     &\multicolumn{3}{c|}{{\thead{\textbf{IEEE}\\\textit{(HuB)}}}}\\
     \hline
     &{\thead{EVR \\ $|\lambda_2/\lambda_1|\cdot 10^{-5}$}}
     &OV
     &\thead{\% Optima-\\lity Gap}
     &{\thead{EVR \\ $|\lambda_2/\lambda_1|\cdot 10^{-5}$}}
     &OV
     &\thead{\% Optima-\\lity Gap}
     &{\thead{EVR \\ $|\lambda_2/\lambda_1|\cdot 10^{-5}$}}
     &OV
     &\thead{\% Optima-\\lity Gap}
     &{\thead{EVR \\ $|\lambda_2/\lambda_1|\cdot 10^{-5}$}}
     &OV
     &\thead{\% Optima-\\lity Gap}
     &{\thead{EVR \\ $|\lambda_2/\lambda_1|\cdot 10^{-5}$}}
     &OV
     &\thead{\% Optima-\\lity Gap}\\
     \hline
\end{tabular}
%       \begin{tablenotes}\scriptsize
%           \centering
%           \item LM: Load Model \hspace{1em} MG: Micro Grid \hspace{1em} \hspace{1em} IT: Italian \hspace{1em} $\dagger$: Memory Limit \hspace{1em} \\ \textit{LuB}: Lightly Unbalanced \hspace{1em} \textit{MuB}: Moderately Unbalanced \hspace{1em} \textit{HuB}: Highly Unbalanced
%       \end{tablenotes}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not the best solution, but this will fit the page.  I assume you intend to add more rows.  Otherwise you should use table instead of table*.

You do NOT mess with margins for a publication.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{color,colortbl}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[p]
  \rotatebox{90}{\begin{minipage}{\textheight}
        \centering
        \caption{Quality and Computational Time of Proposed CCI-based SDP Relaxation for Multi-Phase Networks for $R_{gnd}=1\Omega$}
        \scriptsize
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
        \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            \multicolumn{26}{|c|}{\cellcolor{gray!50}\textbf{OF:1}}\\ \hline
            \textbf{LMs}&\multicolumn{5}{c|}{{\thead{\textbf{MG}\\\textit{(LuB)}}}}&\multicolumn{5}{c|}{{\thead{\textbf{IT-37}\\\textit{(MuB)}}}}&\multicolumn{5}{c|}{{\thead{\textbf{IT-111}$^\dagger$\\\textit{(MuB)}}}}&\multicolumn{5}{c|}{{\thead{\textbf{Cigre}\\\textit{(HuB)}}}}&\multicolumn{5}{c|}{{\thead{\textbf{IEEE}\\\textit{(HuB)}}}}\\ \hline
            &{\thead{EVR \\$|\lambda_2|/|\lambda_1| \times 10^{-5}$}}&OV&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{\% Optimality Gap}&{\thead{EVR \\$|\lambda_2|/|\lambda_1| \times 10^{-5}$}}&OV&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{\% Optimality Gap}&{\thead{EVR \\$|\lambda_2|/|\lambda_1| \times 10^{-5}$}}&OV&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{\% Optimality Gap}&{\thead{EVR \\$|\lambda_2|/|\lambda_1| \times 10^{-5}$}}&OV&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{\% Optimality Gap}&{\thead{EVR \\$|\lambda_2|/|\lambda_1| \times 10^{-5}$}}&OV&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{\% Optimality Gap}\\ \hline 
        \end{tabular}}
%       \begin{tablenotes}\scriptsize
%           \centering 
%           \item LM: Load Model \hspace{1em} MG: Micro Grid \hspace{1em} \hspace{1em} IT: Italian \hspace{1em} $\dagger$: Memory Limit \hspace{1em} \\ \textit{LuB}: Lightly Unbalanced \hspace{1em} \textit{MuB}: Moderately Unbalanced \hspace{1em} \textit{HuB}: Highly Unbalanced
%       \end{tablenotes}
        \label{Table_3}
    \end{minipage}}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```